# How to create and link a ~/bin folder to contain executables.

Tags: executable

Is it possible to create a folder E.G.`~/bin` which contains executables, and once a file is added to this folder, it is executable from command line. (Just like an executable in /bin)

Comment: A file isn't exectuable from the fact that it's located in `/bin`, it must have the executable bit set. (e.g. with `chmod +x <file>`)

Comment: @AlexR. I am looking for the ability to run executables without path, regardless of my current working directory. Not `chmod +x <file>`, something much easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to be able to call these executables without typing out the full path each time.  Am I right?

Add your folder to the default path, and that'll do it:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-adding-path/

Comment: Cheers @codenoire

Answer (score 3):

Just create a folder `~/bin`. Add the following line in your `~/.bashrc`,

```
export PATH=/home/$USER/bin:$PATH
```

Source `~/.bashrc` from terminal as,

```
. ~/.bashrc
```

Put files with execution permission inside `~/bin`.

Answer (score 0):

Just create the folder and insure that you have the following in ~/.profile

```
# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 20.04, a user's `~/.profile` file by defaut contains the statement:

```
# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

Hence all a user has to do is to:

1. Create the private `bin` directory. Either via the nautilus GUI or via issuing the command `mkdir ~/bin` in the terminal.
2. Reload the `~/.profile` file. You do this by typing executing the terminal command `source ~/.profile`.
3. Copy and paste your executable into the `~/bin` directory or create a link to your executable into the `~/bin` directory.